# Join between two tables based on three joining conditions in Hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql, cartesian-product

I want to get below desired output(output table) as shown in the pic below.
I am using below query but getting warning in hive that cartesian product is unsafe feature.

```
select
t1.securitykey as securitykey,
t2.sector as sector,
t2.industrysubgroup as industrysubgroup  
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on (t1.securitykey=t2.key1 or t1.securitykey=t2.key2 or t1.securitykey= t2.key3);
```

table1

| SecurityKey |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

table2

| key1 | key2 | key3 | sector | industrysubgroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 9 | Electronics | US electronincs |
| 5 | 2 | 10 | Industrial | Defense |
| 6 | 8 | 3 | Consumer | entertainment |

table3

| key1 | sector | industrysubgroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronics | US electronincs |
| 2 | Industrial | Defense |
| 3 | Consumer | entertainment |
| 4 | (null) | (null) |

could you please guide?

Comment: you received some solutions. But I tried your code and it works fine for me. Maybe try one of their solutions. or add [a (better) Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join 3 times by different columns and use coalesce() or case expressions:

```
select
t1.securitykey as securitykey,
coalesce(t2.sector,t3.sector,t4.sector) as sector,
coalesce(t2.industrysubgroup,t3.industrysubgroup,t4.industrysubgroup) as industrysubgroup  
from table1 t1 
     left join table2 t2 on t1.securitykey=t2.key1 
     left join table2 t3 on t1.securitykey=t2.key2
     left join table2 t4 on t1.securitykey=t2.key3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it

```
select * from table1 as t1
left join (
     select key1 as securitykey, sector, industrysubgroup from table2
     union all
     select key2 as securitykey, sector, industrysubgroup from table2
     union all
     select key3 as securitykey, sector, industrysubgroup from table2
 ) as t2 on t1.securitykey=t2.securitykey
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problem here. It works fine with your example. Maybe the test data are missing something.

```sql
WITH table1 AS
  (SELECT 1 AS securityKey
   UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 4),
     table2 AS
  (SELECT 1 AS key1,
          7 AS key2,
          9 AS key3,
          'electronics' AS sector,
          'us electronics' AS industrysubgroup
   UNION ALL SELECT 5,
                    2,
                    10,
                    'indus',
                    'defense'
   UNION ALL SELECT 6,
                    8,
                    3,
                    'consumer',
                    'entertainment')
SELECT t1.securitykey AS securitykey,
       t2.sector AS sector,
       t2.industrysubgroup AS industrysubgroup
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.securitykey=t2.key1
                        OR t1.securitykey=t2.key2
                        OR t1.securitykey= t2.key3);
```